# Vaadin Button Submit

Tags: button, vaadin

I am using a Vaadin table to display some reprts. While my submit button is working, if I click again it's showing the same data multiple times (duplicates). My code is

```
Button executeSearchButton = new Button("Search");
executeSearchButton.addListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        if(caseId != null || sitename != null || menunames != null )
        runSerachPage(searchTable, caseId.getValue().toString(), sitename.getValue().toString(), menunames);
    }
});
```

Comment: maybe remove all items from the container or table first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you doesn't clear table before inserting new records.
I assume that you should have something like table.removeAllItems() in runSerachPage before adding new items.